# KendoUI DataViz duplicate category values

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have a Column chart that I have duplicate category values for (because the item it represents was "reborn") and I want to display both individually-but it appears that Kendo takes only one unique category and so ignores the second value. For example:

```
Items: [
{category: 1, value: 1}, 
{category: 2, value: 2},
{category: 1, value: 3} ]
```

So I want three column markers, but instead I get only two:

```
Items: [
{category: 2, value: 2},
{category: 1, value: 3} ]
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this? I tried calling it the Xfield in the series definition, because on other non-categorical charts you can have multiple x values-but it didnt work. I would like to keep it a column chart, but it seems like I may not have a choice...however please let me know if you have a workaround I haven't thought of. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have your categoryField defined in the series definition ?  Something like

```
series: [{ field: 'value', categoryField: 'category', type: 'column' }]
```

I get a chart with only two category columns (http://jsbin.com/AcetIXAL/1/edit). But if I define the category in the categoryAxis as in

```
series: [{ field: 'value', type: 'column' }],
categoryAxis: { field: 'category' },
```

I get all three columns (http://jsbin.com/AcetIXAL/2/edit).

Comment: That was it, thanks so much! Weird, but I can kinda see why that might happen. Thanks again-I really appreciate it!